# plot boxplot only for numeric variable (Jupyter)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to find outliers for my numerical columns in a DataFrame.
I don't want to repeat this code for every numeric columns. Any idea to do it in one time please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig , ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
sns.boxplot(customer.revenue)
```